# No such element or plugin 'fakesink'

Tags: linux, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I need to use fakesink element in my gstreamer pipeline, but when i check in terminal

```
gst-inspect-1.0 fakesink
No such element or plugin 'fakesink'
```

How to install fakesink plugin (Linux)?

Answer (score 0):

Fakesink plugin is a part of coreelements(Core plugins), hence it should be available if you have installed Gstreamer properly.
For Gstreamer installation you can refer to [Gstreamer Installation](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/installing/on-linux.html?gi-language=c).

If installed correctly then also you are facing problem, then you can look for GST_PLUGIN_PATH environment variable, which gst-inspect-1.0 uses for scanning the plugins,
you can refer [this](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/gstreamer/running.html?gi-language=c) for more clarity.